# Changing src of img using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I know this question has been asked before, but my code still isn't working and I don't know why; I'm trying to make a chrome extension that changes images of class 'profilePic img' with a click

This is my code so far:
background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com") != -1) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            "file": "contentscript.js"
        }, function () { 
            console.log("Script Executed"); 
        });
    }
});
```

contentscript.js:

```
alert("alert");
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).find('.profilePic img').attr('src', 'second.jpeg')    
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "stuff",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  // Recommended
  "description": "replaces fb profile pictures",
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "second.jpeg"
  ],
 "background":{
            "scripts":["background.js"],
            "page": "background.html"
        },
         "permissions":["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":["http://www.facebook.com/*"],
            "js":["jquery-2.1.4.min.js","background.js","contentscript.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_title": "testing"
}
}
```

alert pops up just fine, but nothing is changed...I have jquery already included in my manifest
edit: I think this is a problem with uploading jquery, as the console log error is '$ is not defined'. Sorry! Complete beginner here :(

Comment: You mention `contentscript.js` in one place, but `content.js` in another.

Comment: Show us the whole content.js code please

Comment: Need to see the HTML. I think I know the issue, just need to make sure.

Comment: Looks like the function is called OK (as the alert fires), but does `.profilePic img` exist in the initial HTML?

Comment: and I'm just trying to change the fb profile pics with an extension; the exact class is <img class="profilePic img" src=.....>

Comment: Maybe try `$(document).find('.profilePic img').attr('src', 'second.jpeg')`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely occurring because the profilePic class is used on an `img` tag. Facebook profile pictures use the class `profilePic` with a selector , which is probably what's tripping you up. If it looked something like this your code in its current form would work, it would seek the `profilePic` class and then find any `img` tags within it, replacing the `src` attribute.

```
<div class="profilePic">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
</div>
```

However because you have the `profilePic` class on the image itself you'll need to refactor your jQuery so it looks like this

```
$(".profilePic").attr("src","second.jpeg");
```

You could also do something like this, I'm not entirely sure how Facebook is put together usually, but this was taken from my page.

```
$("#fbPageFinchProfilePic img").attr("src","second.jpeg");
```

You can test this out using this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u8zr55vz/1/

I hope that helps! Be sure to read up on the jQuery .attr() [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for more information.

Comment: What does the console log say? It should provide some sort of error. It would be appreciated if you can provide the rest of your code too.

Comment: sorry, I think this is a problem with loading jquery; it says '$ is not defined'. I'm editing the question the provide all of my code now!

Comment: Few questions: Do you have the jQuery file in your chrome extension folder? It should be in the same folder as contentscript.js, Secondly you might need to adjust "matches" in your json so it authorizes the scripts to run on https pages, currently it will only execute on plain http. Check out examples of this here:  http://carl-topham.com/theblog/post/creating-chrome-extension-uses-jquery-manipulate-dom-page/

Comment: I do have the jquery file in my extension folder; I'll try that, thanks a lot :)